# How does cryptsy.com currency trading works?

Tags: litecoin, address, dogecoin, sell-bitcoins, cryptsy

I am using cryptsy and i am unclear how cryptsy works, At first i deposited dogecoin to newly generated address and then I made the sell offer for DOGE/LTC, now i am having some LTC but i don't see any Litecoin address in cryptsy

My questions are,

1. In which address my LTC balance available?
2. If coins are stored in db level, how it is possible to withdraw that coin?

Answer (score 1):

You do not own a LTC-address (or BTC, or any other altcoin) on cryptsy or any other virtual currency exchange site. You can however see your balance of all crypto currencies in the 'Balance' tab. When you scroll down, you will see the LiteCoin with your current available balance and the balance that is in possible orders. If you want to have your LTC in an address, you should download an LTC-wallet app, and create a wallet in there, and then withdraw (from cryptsy) to that wallet.

And your second question: yes, cryptsy is a crypto currency exchange. So far there is no option to trade in any real currency, but I see that option is coming in a week or so, because this text is above the BTC/USD market

```
This market is for Verified Accounts Only. The User Verifications system will open within the next week.
```

Anyhow, what happens when you withdraw LTC to your own wallet, is that cryptsy looks at deposit wallets (for other people) they own. For example person `A`, `B` and `C` have all a different deposit wallet, and they deposited 1, 2 and 3 LTC respectively. You had fun trading, and want to withdraw 2.5 LTC. Cryptsy sends 2.5 LTC from the deposit wallet from person `C`, so there is only 0.5 LTC left in that wallet and you have (after confirmation) 2.5 LTC in your wallet.

When you trade, there is no 'real' LTC being transferred between wallets, only on withdrawl and deposits. Otherwise you cannot trade that fast (and other disadvantages, like fees and huge blocks)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know much about Cryptsy, but why do you assume you should have an LTC address already?  Maybe the way out works is your LTC balance is just a number in their database.  If you want to use the funds you should look for a "withdraw" option and learn how that works.

And to answer your second question, yes, it looks like Cryptsy is an exchange but you should know that because you already traded doge for LTC on cryptsy.